# Replacing words in a dataframe given a list of common misspellings in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I have a large dataset with one column of multi-word names that contain frequent spelling errors. We have a separate dataframe with a column of common misspellings. We want to replace all of the misspellings in the large dataset with the one correct spelling.

This is what I tried so far (with a simplified dataset). It does replace the word but I'm finding that there are extra characters at the end of the word each time. I believe it's replacing the word (but not the whole word) every time it finds one of the common misspellings but I want it to replace the whole word if it's an exact match to that misspelling (but not necessarily to the whole name). I'm guessing there is something I could do with regex?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'city': ['City of Cleveland', 'City of Clvland', 'City of Boston', 'City New York', 'City of Clev', 'City of Miami', 'City of Cland', 'Cle Ci']})

df_spelling = pd.DataFrame({'spellings': ['Clvland','Clev', 'Cland']})


for item in df_spelling['spellings']:
 df['city'] = df['city'].str.replace(item,'Cleveland')
```

This code gives the output in the attached image.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMLfL.png)

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the previous answerer has not tried their code, as if they do they will get the following error, since `df['city']` is a pandas Series, not a string:

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

The general idea of using RegEx to match only whole words is correct, though. `Series.str.replace` accepts a parameter `regex`, so there is no need to use the `re` module. Also `\b` in RegEx is the most concise way to match word boundaries (which may be space characters, or the beginning/end of the string).

The following gives the output you're looking for:

```
for item in df_spelling['spellings']:
    df['city'] = df['city'].str.replace(rf"\b{item}\b", 'Cleveland', regex=True)
```

Comment: You are right. I wasn't able to test the code atm. Just wanted to get the idea out there. Thanks for clearing it up.

Comment: But I'm not sure that your regex pattern here works. Shouldn't it be `\b\S*Clev\S*\b` to match the whole word containing the mispelling?

Comment: It's a little misleading as the examples given don't look like very likely misspellings of 'Cleveland', but I believe the OP is just looking for word-for-word matches. They write "I want it to replace the whole word if it's an exact match to that misspelling", and the code I posted outputs "City of Cleveland" correctly for all of the misspelt examples so I believe it satisfies their spec.

Comment: You're right. Fair point.

Comment: Thanks both, ljdyer's code is working in my actual dataset. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

We can construct a singular regex pattern with your spellings DataFrame that matches the whole cell, rather than trying to fix certain pieces:

```
pattern = '|'.join(f'(.*{i}.*)' for i in df_spelling.spellings)
df.city = df.city.replace(pattern, 'City of Cleveland', regex=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                city
0  City of Cleveland
1  City of Cleveland
2     City of Boston
3      City New York
4  City of Cleveland
5      City of Miami
6  City of Cleveland
7             Cle Ci
```

[Underlying Regex Idea](https://regexr.com/6uhan)

Answer (score 0):

In case there are a lot of misspelling variants, you should use a regex trie. Also, you can build a single regex with that approach without looping over the spelling items.

Make sure you install [trieregex](https://github.com/ermanh/trieregex) library beforehand, and then use

```
import pandas as pd
from trieregex import TrieRegEx

df = pd.DataFrame({'city': ['City of Cleveland', 'City of Clvland', 'City of Boston', 'City New York', 'City of Clev', 'City of Miami', 'City of Cland', 'Cle Ci']})
df_spelling = pd.DataFrame({'spellings': ['Clvland','Clev', 'Cland']})
pattern = fr'\b({TrieRegEx(*df_spelling["spellings"].values.tolist()).regex()})\b' # => \b(Cl(?:vland|and|ev))\b
df['city'] = df['city'].str.replace(pattern,'Cleveland', regex=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> df['city']
0    City of Cleveland
1    City of Cleveland
2       City of Boston
3        City New York
4    City of Cleveland
5        City of Miami
6    City of Cleveland
7               Cle Ci
Name: city, dtype: object
>>>
```

See the [resulting regex pattern](https://regex101.com/r/oG6qRx/1) that matches the misspellings as efficient as possible.

Answer (score -2):

Could something like this work:

```
import re
...
df['city'] = df['city'].str.replace(r'\b{}\b'.format(item), 'Cleveland', regex=True)
```

Basically matches the whole word that contains the mistyped string.